# Deploying/Re-Deploying SAS job in DIS via Script

Tags: shell, unix, sas, sas-metadata

Is there a possibility to deploy or redeploy a SAS job (Data Integration Studio) via a shell script ?

Also is there a way to create its **SPK** file via script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy DI jobs from commandline, see here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/65807/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm

Comment: In my case, the SAS software is installed in Windows, and the SAS server is in Unix. All the deployed jobs and other information are in the Unix server. The link provided suggests to alter certain files in the windows environment, will this work correctly ?

Comment: Yes, this will work, You can deploy jobs to a UNIX server from a Windows client. The documentation is very weak, and the configuration is complex, so expect to spend some time getting it to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have imported and exported objects into SAS DIS via shell script use this sas [ExportPackage](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisag/64088/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003261084.htm) utility. I personally find it way more convenient as compared to window method. However, for it to work you need to have X-windows Environment, i used Xming for it.
As for deploying Jobs, never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

To redeploy jobs DI Studio versions 4.901 and higher have a DepoyJobs tool which is designed to perform this function: read more in the [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/69395/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm). It is available on the server. Older versions had a similar but much more restrictive client tool using ant.

Also see [Paper 1067-2017 An Introduction to the Improved SAS® Data Integration Studio Batch Deployment Utility on UNIX](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/69395/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm) by Jeff Dyson, The Financial Risk Group, which gives a run through on how to use it.